# Add logic inside button click inside a custom control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, user-controls

I am making a custom control that looks like this (there is a label on the right of the button): [image]

I want the user to be able to define what the button does in his code, but still execute some code on the click event on top of the user's code.

What I want to execute :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Button1.Enabled = False
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Gray
    Label1.Text = "In Progress"

End Sub
```

then after this is executed the user's on click event would trigger.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With "the user" you mean a developer which uses that user control, right? Well, the most common thing is to raise an event which the next developer can use to implement his own logic. This is exactly the same as you do - you use the Click-Event of the button.

So basically, take your code and add the `RaiseEvent` below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Button1.Enabled = False
    Label1.ForeColor = Color.Gray
    Label1.Text = "In Progress"

    ' this does not affect your code but provides a "hook" for
    ' other developers
    RaiseEvent OnButtonClick(Button1)

End Sub
```

Now you need to define the event itself like this ...

```
Public Event OnButtonClick(ByVal sender As Control)
```

... btw, you can pass other stuff (or nothing at all) as arguments. Sending the button as sender is just a habit.

A developer using your user control can attach a so called "Handler" to implement code as soon as the button was clicked, for example:

```
 AddHandler UserControl1.OnButtonClick, AddressOf OnUserControlButtonClick
```

This code line should only be executed once, so typically it is placed in the `Form_Load` event.

Now, in this case the button click is routed to a method called `OnUserControlButtonClick()` which meets the signature of the event: that means it has one argument which is the sender.

```
Private Sub OnUserControlButtonClick(ByVal sender as Control)
    ' custom logic here ...
End Sub
```

There are so many examples on the web, you could start [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/event-vbnet).